# Error after making virtual host

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu, codeigniter-3

I have a project developed in Codeigniter. It works fine when I try to access it on the browser at localhost using `localhost/bmlivenew`. But after making its virtual host, when I access it on the browser using www.bmlivenew.com , it displays the website but at the top of it, it shows an error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Undefined variable: designer_images
>       Filename: controllers/Designs.php
>       Line Number: 42
>       Backtrace:
>       File: /var/www/html/bmlivenew/application/controllers/Designs.php
>       Line: 42
>       Function: _error_handler
>       File: /var/www/html/bmlivenew/index.php
>       Line: 324
>       Function: require_once

Whereas, the variable `$designer_images` is properly defined and it does not throw such an error if I try to access the website using localhost/bmlivenew.

Bunch of codes where I have defined the `$designer_images` in the Designs controller.

```
$designers  = $this->interior_images_m->get_by($cond);
foreach ($designers as $key => $designer) {

            $designer_images = $this->interior_new_m->get_by(array('id'=>$designer->name));
            $designers[$key]->images = $designer_images; 

        }


        $this->data['names'] = $designer_images;
        $this->data['designers'] = $designers;

        // Load View
        $this->load->view("frontend/ourdesign",$this->data);
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: show your code also where `designer_images` is

Comment: I have attached my code for designer_images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*initialise  `$designer_images` first, above foreach loop*

Should be like this :

```
$designers = $this->interior_images_m->get_by($cond);
$designer_images = NULL; 
foreach ($designers as $key => $designer) 
{ 
    $designer_images = $this->interior_new_m->get_by(array('id' => $designer->name)); 
    $designers[$key]->images = $designer_images; 
} 
$this->data['names'] = $designer_images; 
$this->data['designers'] = $designers;
```

Comment: It works that way, but just for the knowledge sake could you please tell me how it works fine without being initialised in one case but in the other case it does not.

Comment: this is because the scope of variable is within foreach loop as u do, the other case u talking is just put `$this->data['names'] = $designer_images;` within your foreach loop then it will not throw a notice

Comment: by the way if my answers helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green and do upvote also

Comment: The cases that I was talking about is, by accessing it using www.bmlivenew.com (after doing virtual host), it works with initialisation but even without initialisation it works if I access the website using localhost/bmlivenew. Just was curious what possibly could be the reason for it.

Comment: localhost sometimes ignores notices like file name case , notices, but if u run same thing on live server it gives notices or error, here virtual host is treated as live server, that may be the case

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: my pleasure , happy coding